# what is the time mentioned after date (1962-07-03+02:00) the +02:00?

Tags: earth, rotation, time, clock

i was retrieving a some personalities `birthday` date through computer programming

when i retrieve a person's birthday the result was

`1962-07-03+02:00`   [this is tom cuise's birthday for information]

In the above result i could understand his birthday is on 1962-07-03 ,

But what is `+02:00` , is that the location of birth or GMT ?

for more information the data is retrieved from the URL

http://dbpedia.org/page/Tom_Cruise

sorry to ask this question here , I asked this question because it deals with time and i believe astronomers can help with this

Comment: In ISO8601 (the international standard for date and time representation) the time zone is indicated by a time preceded by a + or -.

Comment: Conrad's answer should sufficiently answer the question. This really has no direct relationship with Astronomy though, as it's essentially about a date formatting schema.

Comment: @ConradTurner: It would be odd to include the time zone but not the time -- and particularly odd to represent Tom Cruise's birth date with the `+2:00` time zone (2 hours east of UTC), since he was born in New York. In any case I don't see `1962-07-03+02:00` on that web page.

Comment: @ Keith Thompson I am not responsible for what the OP wrote, just for the information that +02:00 in an iso date/time specification denotes the time zone. That it does not make sense as a time zone or the time of birth for the individual in question is not my problem, take it up with the OP.

Comment: @KeithThompson i have checked with many people , but for every one(even they born in different ISO timings) the +02:00 came during the programming result. There is some problem with the query i guess. I just wanted to know the +02:00. Now i understood . But i don't know why for many people +02:00 coming as result. If you want more information the url which you test is [link](www.dbpedia/sparql) and the query is               PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX res: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?string 
WHERE { 
 res:Tom_Cruise dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?string .
}

Comment: @ConradTurner: No need to be defensive, I was just making a comment.

Comment: Likely related to default settings for the DB rather than individual stored data points. It's senseless value for the data stored. Possibly due to the information being stored as a Datetime with omitted time value than simply as a Date value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the `+02:00` is the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) syntax for the time zone. Specifically, it indicates a time zone 2 hours east of UTC.

`whois dbpedia.org` indicates that the site is hosted in Berlin, Germany, which is consistent with the `+02:00` time zone.

The fact that the data includes the date and time zone but not the time is probably an error. This particular datum `1962-07-03+02:00` is Tom Cruise's birthday; in fact he was born on that day in Syracuse, New York.

A data representation that includes a date and time zone but no time is peculiar, and I'm not sure that it conforms to the ISO 8601 standard. The description in the Wikipedia article seems to imply that a time zone can only follow a time. I haven't checked the standard itself.

A representation of just the date: `1962-07-03` would make more sense, and would be more useful. This is probably a bug in the software that runs dbpedia.org.